# Bundling JSF in WAR for Payara fails with JSF1051 GlassFishInjectionProvider does not extend DiscoverableInjectionProvider

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4, payara

I need to bundle JSF implementation in my WAR file due to known bug in the original mojarra implementation.

I am not allowed to replace the JSF implementation in the modules, so i am using the useBundledJsf property.

Running Payara Version: Payara Server  4.1.1.164 #badassfish (build 28)
This versions should support useBundledJsf properly.

I have added this to my glassfish-web.xml:

```
  <class-loader delegate="false" />
  <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
```

and added the javax.faces dependecy to my pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following error and all injections are failing.

```
SEVERE: JSF1051: Service entry 'org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider' does not extend DiscoverableInjectionProvider. Entry will be ignored.
```

I have tried to add the weld-integration.jar to my project but it still produces the JSF1051 error following by:

```
Unable to create a new instance of 'org.jboss.weld.jsf.ConversationAwareViewHandler'
```

The dependency for the weld-integration i have used:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.main.web</groupId>
<artifactId>weld-integration</artifactId>
<version>4.1.2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra feature to make this easier in Payara Server 171 which was added specifically to make these scenarios work properly.

From the documentation:

> It’s possible to configure an extreme isolation level on the class loading delegation for deployed applications. With this extreme isolation behavior, a deployed application can force the server to load only classes from libraries included on Payara Server that belong to whitelisted packages defined on its deployment descriptors.
>
> To configure whitelist packaging you can use the `<whitelist-package>` element on the glassfish-web.xml (WAR artifacts) or the glassfish-application.xml (EAR artifacts). This element can be included multiple times to whitelist multiple packages. Here is an example of whitelisting both the Google Guava and Jackson packages for a WAR application:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
> <glassfish-web-app error-url="">
>   ...
>   <whitelist-package>com.google.guava</whitelist-package>
>   <whitelist-package>com.fasterxml.jackson</whitelist-package>
> </glassfish-web-app>
> ```
>
> The whitelist syntax is simple: Define the name of the package which contains the classes in question. For example writing `com.google` would whitelist all Google libraries included on the server, while writing `com.google.guava` would only whitelist the Google Guava library instead.

[Extreme Classloading Isolation](https://docs.payara.fish/v/next/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html#extreme-classloading-isolation)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but i am not sure what i should whitelist here. all packages used by facelets are already whitelisted (Default Whitelisted Classes): com.sun, javax and the package in the error message org.glassfish. It still tries to load JSF externaly and the error is still there.